# Manually editing cmake files to point to the right place

Tags: include, makefile, cmake

I have run `cmake` on a package, but the resultant `make` fails because certain packages aren't being included properly. Can I edit the specific `find*.cmake` files to point to the correct place?

Currently, the corresponding cmake file is `find_tbb.make`:

```
include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)

check_include_file_cxx(tbb/tbb.h HAVE_TBB)
```

I suppose that this means it is looking in `tbb/tbb.h` for the files. My files aren't there, so can I edit this line of the file to point to a better place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to edit the generated CMakeCache.txt instead.

CMake has been designed with the thought that for some reason, the Find* modules can fail, leaving the task to the user to fill the correct values, usually left blank in the cache, or with a value like `ttb_NOT_FOUND`.

The `ccmake` or `cmake-gui` tools are there specifically for that, they present a friendly interface to edit entries in the CMake cache.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to edit the standard CMake module files on your system. Editing those files may break other CMake projects. It also makes your CMake list file less portable.

A better option is to "fork" those CMake module files and make them part of your project. In your outermost project folder create a folder `CMake` and copy the `find*.cmake` files you need to adapt to it. Make your changes and then in your root `CMakeLists.txt` modify the CMake module search path to look in your project's `CMake` folder first:

```
project (MyProject)

set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
...
```

The module files in the project's `CMake` folder will override the standard module files.